# Is $\text{Hom}(\prod_p \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z, \Bbb Q) = 0$ possible without choice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

That divisible abelian groups are precisely the injective groups is [equivalent to choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/586179/98602); indeed, there are some models of ZF with no injective groups at all. Now, given that $\Bbb Q$ is injective, one immediately has that $\text{Hom}(\prod_p \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z, \Bbb Q)$ is nontrivial (pick an element of infinite order in the former group; then the definition of injective gives a nonzero map to $\Bbb Q$ factoring the inclusion $\Bbb Z \hookrightarrow \Bbb Q$.)

Now, assuming that $\Bbb Q$ is *not* injective does not obviously prove that $\text{Hom}(\prod_p \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z, \Bbb Q)$ is trivial, whence: is there a model of ZF in which this is true?

Comment: As for where the problem came from: [Pedro Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19705596#19705596) recently posted the above question in chat.

Comment: (Note the argument shows more generally that in ZFC any abelian group $G$ with an element of infinite order has ${\rm Hom}(G,\Bbb Q)\neq 0$)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It's the other direction: there's an injective morphism $\Bbb Z \to G$, which (by definition of injective object) you may then compose with a map $f: G \to \Bbb Q$ to factor the inclusion $\Bbb Z \hookrightarrow \Bbb Q$ as $\Bbb Z \to G \xrightarrow{f} \Bbb Q$. It's this map $f: G \to \Bbb Q$ that's the desired one.

Comment: Well. It's a very nice question. We know it is consistent that every homomorphism from a Polish group (like this product) to $\Bbb Q$ is continuous, but continuity implies constant only when the domain is connected, and here we have a totally disconnected group. So some additional argument is probably needed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your last comment was almost there: The only continuous homomorphism from a compact group to $\mathbb{Q}$ is the trivial map because its image is a compact subgroup of rationals.

Comment: @OohAah: Ah!!! Of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Work in ZF + DC + "every set of reals has the Baire property". Put $G = \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$. Suppose $\phi:\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Q}$ is a non constant additive function. Let $H = ker(\phi)$ (so $H$ has Baire property). Since all subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ are infinite, $H$ must have infinitely many cosets in $G$. By Pettis' theorem, $H$ is clopen. Since $G$ is compact, $H$ has only finitely many cosets: A contradiction.

Addendum: This is also true for any compact Polish group by the same argument.

Comment: +1 but I don't get the first implication -- how are you using a property of subsets of reals to conclude something about $\prod \mathbb{Z}/p$ ?

Comment: @hunter In set theory, as maybe you know, reals denotes an element of $\Bbb{N}^\omega$, the Baire space. Also, it is known that every Polish space is a continuous image of Baire space. From this, you can prove that every subset $A$ of Polish space has some *analytic set* $B$ whose symmetric difference between $A$ and $B$ are meager, and analytic set has property of Baire.

Comment: great! seems like this is the right answer

Comment: Why $H$ is meager? In fact you can show that it's not meager. It contains an open set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, you are right. I tried a different argument.

Comment: That seems much more likely. Although the finite set of primes, I think, can be found from compactness. No?

Comment: Yes, compactness of $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$ was essential in the proof.

Comment: I think that you should probably add that we use $\sf DC$ (for Pettis theorem, I think) and that indeed $\sf ZF+DC+BP$ is consistent (relative to the consistency of $\sf ZFC$).

Comment: Which theorem of Pettis do you mean?

Comment: The one that says that a non meager subgroup of a topological group that has Baire property is clopen.

Answer (score 5):

I'm upgrading my comment to an answer, since it offers a similar, albeit different, argument than OohAah's answer.

---

Consider a model of $\sf ZF+DC+BP$ (where $\sf BP$ is the statement that every set of reals have the Baire property), this theory was shown consistent by Solovay and Shelah (the former did it from an inaccessible cardinal, and the latter removed that requirement).

In such model every homomorphism from a Polish group to $\Bbb Q$ is continuous. Therefore a homomorphism from a compact Polish group to $\Bbb Q$ must have a compact image, but the only compact subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ is $\{0\}$, since compact subsets of $\Bbb Q$ are bounded and nontrivial subgroups are not.

Comment: I'd be very interested to hear about the downvote constructively.

Comment: (Judging by timing, it seems that someone perhaps thinks that I stole the argument from OohAah's answer, but I should point out that (1) my original comment was there well before the first answer; (2) the original answer by OoAah suffered from problems and the revision history as well comments to that answer, all indicate that my comments helped improve it. So I don't see how me posting my idea as an answer, with the last bit of the argument complemented by OohAah's comment reply to mine is any wrong.)

Comment: I'm starting to think that the two downvotes are neither coincidental, nor has anything to do with the text of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

A related question is the following: does there exist a model of ZF where choice fails but the hom-set is nontrivial? The following is an answer by [Andreas Blass](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/48510/andreas-blass).

> The answer to that is yes.  The reason is that the failure of choice can be such as to involve only very large sets, much larger than the groups in the question.  That is, one can start with a model of ZFC, where the Hom-set in question is nonzero, and then one can force over this model to add new subsets of some cardinal kappa that is much bigger than the cardinal of the continuum, and then one can pass to a symmetric inner model to falsify the axiom of choice; all of this can be done in such a way as not to adjoin any new elements in the product of Z_p's, so that product is the same in the new model as in the original, and all its non-zero homomorphisms to Q in the original ZFC model remain perfectly good nonzero homomorphisms in the new model that violates choice.